# About how to find all desired format in a str

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this format,

```
s = '[aaa]foo[bbb]bar[ccc]foobar'
```

Actually the text is Chinese car review like this

```
【最满意】整车都很满意，最满意就是性价比，...【空间】空间真的超乎想象，毫不夸张，...【内饰】内饰还可以吧，没有多少可以说的...
```

Now I want to split it to these parts

```
[aaa]foo
[bbb]bar
[ccc]foobar
```

first I tried

```
>>> re.findall(r'\[.*?\].*?',s)
['[aaa]', '[bbb]', '[ccc]']
```

only got first half.

Then I tried

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\[.*?\].*?)\[?',s)
['[aaa]', '[bbb]', '[ccc]']
```

still only got first half

At last I have to get the two parts respectively then zip them

```
>>> re.findall(r'\[.*?\]',s)
['[aaa]', '[bbb]', '[ccc]']

>>> re.split(r'\[.*?\]',s)
['', 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

>>> for t in zip(re.findall(r'\[.*?\]',s),[e for e in re.split(r'\[.*?\]',s) if e]):
...    print(''.join(t))
...
[aaa]foo
[bbb]bar
[ccc]foobar
```

So I want to know if exists some regex could directly split it to these parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if input string format is "strict enough", it's possible to try something w/o regexp. It may look as a microoptimisation, but could be interesting as a challenge.

```
result = map(lambda x: '[' + x, s[1:].split("["))
```

So I tried to check performance on a 1Mil iterations and here are my results (seconds):

```
result = map(lambda x: '[' + x, s[1:].split("[")) # 0.89862203598
result = re.findall(r'\[[^]]+\][^\[\]]+', s) # 1.48306798935
result = re.findall(r'\[.+?\]\w+', s) # 1.47224497795
result = re.findall(r'(\[\w*\]\w+)', s) # 1.47370815277
```

Comment: very smart way!

Comment: and I think `['[' + x for x in s[1:].split("[")]` is more easy to understand than `map lambda ` way

Comment: @zhuguowei you are right. Also your method is even faster: 0.669850111008s

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches:

```
import re

s = '[aaa]foo[bbb]bar[ccc]foobar'
result = re.findall(r'\[[^]]+\][^\[\]]+', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['[aaa]foo', '[bbb]bar', '[ccc]foobar']
```

---

- `\[` or `\]` - matches the bracket literally
- `[^]]+` - matches one or more characters except `]`
- `[^\[\]]+` - matches any character(s) except brackets `\[\]`

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work:

```
r'\[.+?\]\w+'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\[\w*\]\w+)",s)
['[aaa]foo', '[bbb]bar', '[ccc]foobar']
```

**Explanation**:

- parenthesis means the group to search. Witch group:
- it should start by a braked `\[` followed by some letters `\w`
- then the matched braked braked `\]` followed by more letters `\w`

Notice you should to escape braked with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[.*?\][a-zA-Z]*
```

This regex should capture anything that start with [somethinghere]Any letters from a to Z

you can play on regex101 to try out different ones and it's easy to make your own regex there

Answer (score 0):

All you need is findall and here is very simple pattern without making it complicated:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'\[\w+\]\w+','[aaa]foo[bbb]bar[ccc]foobar'))
```

output:

```
['[aaa]foo', '[bbb]bar', '[ccc]foobar']
```

Detailed solution:

```
import re
string_1='[aaa]foo[bbb]bar[ccc]foobar'
pattern=r'\[\w+\]\w+'
print(re.findall(pattern,string_1))
```

explanation:

```
\[\w+\]\w+


\[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
```